# How to take specific user logs in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want to record some user activities in my system. Actually what I want looks very similar to admin logs. I can successfully save admin's logs using a code I found on the internet.
There are some important operations in the system. These are;

- User blocking (`is_active = False`)
- DOA table changes (These are called as `approvals | doa table` in admin logs.)
- Role change (These are called as `register | rank change` in admin logs.)
- Creating a new user (These are called as `register | user` in admin logs.)

All of these operations are doing by users whose role is "`Lead`".

This is a code for admin logs:

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(LogEntry)
class LogEntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    date_hierarchy = 'action_time'

    list_filter = [
        'user',
        'content_type',
        'action_flag'
    ]

    search_fields = [
        'object_repr',
        'change_message'
    ]

    list_display = [
        'action_time',
        'user',
        'content_type',
        'object_link',
        'action_flag',
    ]

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_view_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return request.user.is_superuser

    def object_link(self, obj):
        if obj.action_flag == DELETION:
            link = escape(obj.object_repr)
        else:
            ct = obj.content_type
            link = '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (
                reverse('admin:%s_%s_change' % (ct.app_label, ct.model), args=[obj.object_id]),
                escape(obj.object_repr),
            )
        return mark_safe(link)
    object_link.admin_order_field = "object_repr"
    object_link.short_description = "object"
```

And it is look like this:

[image: this]

What sould I do for doing this?